# How do get data from webbrowser in C#

Tags: c#

have a form and one webbrowser now I want to retrieve data displayed on the webbrowser must do?
Div Tags

```
<div id="divTop">

    <div id="text-conent" style="width: 500px; float: right;"></div>
    <div id="grid" style="margin-removed 505px; height: 700px;"></div>

</div>
```

I want to take content from tag div 'text - conent' but do not know how

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. have you tried the example on msdn website? [WebBrowser.DocumentText Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 2):

You can get your webbroswer content with the "WebBrowser.DocumentText" property

Then you can use CSQuery to parse your html for example or any method you like.
(even a regex if you think it's more simple)
If you know JQuery, it'll be easy.

https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

```
var html = myWebBrowser.DocumentText;
var dom = CQ.Create(html);
var divContent = dom.Select("#text-conent").Text();
```

**EDIT**

If you just want to download a page to get the data, you can just remove your webbrowser and use something like that

```
var dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://www.test.com");
var divContent = dom.Select("#text-conent").Text();
richTextBox1.Text = divContent;
```

these 2 lines will do everything.

Comment: Can you give me a demo is not ?

Comment: You can just use CQ.Load method instead of WebBrowser.DocumentText

Comment: it's already a demo code^^ you just need to get the nuget package of CSQuery in visual studio (right click on dependency, select "manage nuget packages" and put csquery in search box), install it and place this code where you need it^^ juste replace "myWebBrowser" by "webBrowser1". divContent will contain the text that you have in your div.

Comment: do you really need to use a webbrowser? don't you just want to get a page from its url and get the content?

Comment: I did as above, but do not get any data at all

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using HtmlAgilityPack to parse from HTML.

In your case the code would be:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
string text = doc.GetElementbyId("text-content").InnerText;
```

**EDIT**

Or you try this instead:

```
text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='divTop']/div[@id='text-content']").InnerText;
```

Comment: code retrieves data from the link you have done, but I did not get the data directly on the webbrowser are displayed

Comment: I edited my post. You just want the content of the div with id text-content?

Comment: Oh, This code does not work with webbrowser is displayed, it only obtained data specified pages, I want to grab data from websites that are displaying webbrowser

Comment: Ah ok so you use a webbrowser control and you want the content out of this html document? i updated my post again.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited as your code but it error
error:
Unable to cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to class type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

Comment: this is a problem well explained in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193253/mshtml-htmlheadelementclass-com-error

Comment: Thank you, but I do not understand how to solve the problem in the other topic, you can answer not me ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one script but it informed error

```
HtmlElement texts = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("text-conent");
           string kq = "";
           foreach (var item in texts.All)
               {
                   kq += item.InnerText + Environment.NewLine;
               }
           richTextBox1.Text = kq;
```

Error :
'object' does not contain a definition for 'innerText' and no extension method 'innerText' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Answer (score 0):

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
           string texts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='text-conent']/p]").InnerText;
           richTextBox1.Text = texts;
```

Comment: it's better to add some explain instead of only code